# Pixel is 4 lines high

Tags: html5-canvas

Pixels get drawed with wrong colors and 4 lines high.

[like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gucPX.png)

```
var cnv = document.getElementById("john");
var ctx = cnv.getContext("2d");
var width = cnv.width;
var height = cnv.height;

//ctx.imageSmoothingEnabled = false;
var imd = ctx.createImageData(width,height);

i = 0;

imd.data[i] = 255;
imd.data[i+1] = 0;
imd.data[i+2] = 0;
imd.data[i+3] = 255;

ctx.putImageData(imd,1,1);
```

https://jsfiddle.net/zzxsvsxy/2/

Answer (score 0):

Problem was caused by setting a height of canvas with CSS:

```
canvas { width: 300px; height: 300px; }
```

Set canvas size only with inline rules:

```
<canvas width="300" height="300"></canvas>
```